# How to create multiple xts objects from one xts object

Tags: r

I have created an 'xts' object from a data frame - the data frame was loaded from a 'csv' file.

The 'xts' object looks like so :-

```
            entitycode,usage
2016-01-01  1,16521
2016-01-01  2,6589
2016-01-02  1,16540
2016-01-02  2,6687
2016-01-03  1,16269
2016-01-03  2,6642
```

There are a total of 1462 records in it - 731 each for each of the entitycodes 1 and 2 from 01/01/2016 through to 31/12/2017 with a frequency of 1 day.

Entitycode 1 & 2 refer to different regions say 'region1' and 'region2'.

Is there a way to create separate 'xts' objects (variables) for entitycodes 1 & 2 (or 'region1' and 'region2') each with 731 rows with names like 'region1_xts' and 'region1_xts'?

Best regards

Deepak

Comment: you can easily subset the data using region code and creates xts object for two regions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend `split`ting the `xts` object resulting in a `list` of `xts` objects

```
split(xts, xts$entitycode)
#$`1`
#           entitycode usage
#2016-01-01          1 16521
#2016-01-02          1 16540
#2016-01-03          1 16269
#
#$`2`
#           entitycode usage
#2016-01-01          2  6589
#2016-01-02          2  6687
#2016-01-03          2  6642
```

You can then use functions of the `*apply` family to easily operate on the different `list` elements (i.e. the `xts` objects).

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.csv(text =
    "      date,entitycode,usage
2016-01-01,  1,16521
2016-01-01,  2,6589
2016-01-02,  1,16540
2016-01-02,  2,6687
2016-01-03,  1,16269
2016-01-03,  2,6642", header = T)

mat <- as.matrix(df[, -1])
rownames(mat) <- df[, 1]
colnames(mat) <- colnames(df)[-1]

xts <- as.xts(mat)
```

Comment: -> Wouldn't the last command 'xts <- as.xts(mat)'  create an xts object which is for combined the 2 entity codes and there would be no way to know which one is for which, isn't it? Or am I reading it wrong? Previously, I did try to use the 'rapply' function on each of the list elements but it erred out. I will make another post showing and you can possibly suggest what was going wrong there. Thanks for this help! I will try it out myself shortly and report.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; I am just creating sample data similar to what you show. If you had provided the `dput` (always recommended) of your `xts` object I wouldn't have had to do this. The key here is to make use of `split` for `xts` objects to give you a `list`.

Comment: OK the. I had never heard of dput(). Henceforth, I will provided the relevant information using dput. Thanks and sorry for the misunderstanding.